# Example of vue2-leaflet and GeoTIFF

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, gis

We're using Vue with [vue2-leaflet](https://github.com/vue-leaflet/Vue2Leaflet) for mapping. Looking how to add a layer of a GeoTIFF image.

Could find two Leaflet plugins for GeoTIFF in [Leaflet plugins page](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) ([Leaflet.CanvasLayer.Field](https://github.com/IHCantabria/Leaflet.CanvasLayer.Field) and [leaflet-geotiff](https://github.com/stuartmatthews/leaflet-geotiff)) but not experienced enough with JS and Vue to understand if\how this helps with Vue.

Any explanation if\how these plugins can work with vue-leaflet, and\or any example of Vue2Leaflet displaying a GeoTIFF image - would be much appreciated.

Thanks!